# Changing phone wallpaper won't work in Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

The program is working good with Activity as super class
but when I change it to Fragment it won't work when I click Button to change wallpaper.

```java
   try {
       myWallpaperManager= WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
       myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bim);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }

   break;

   case R.id.ib:

        i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i,cameraData);
        break;
   case R.id.b2:
                try {
                    myWallpaperManager= WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

                    myWallpaperManager.clear();
                }
                catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                break;
         }
     }
0}
```

I added getActivity() before getApplicationContext();

But it still does't work.

Any help to set ChangeWalpaper in Fragment?

Comment: Possible to add your whole fragment code? Please format it properly in Android Studio Itself before pasting it here.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't post your logcat you can't expect anyone to help you. Also, As far as I am aware there is no such a method as "getActivityContext()".

Please ensure you follow the standards when it comes to asking questions here otherwiese this website looses its quality.
Now from what I understand you are having issues with context.
Please read through this to understand what you are doing.

[this - return self reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

[getContext() - returns Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

[getActivity() - return Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/index.html)

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` is what he has written there, document about it too in your answer. (if you know about it)

Comment: And my favorite part, **no help without logcat**, I am not sure whether you are aware or not, logcats help during crashes or when you are debugging yourself, But cases where code do not work as expected, he is supposed to provide more codes and details, but not logcat.

Comment: Thanks and i'm sorry for the mistakes

Comment: "I added getActivity() before getActivityContext(); " is what he has written below the code extract. Not to sure what you are getting onto me for there @Mohammed Atif. Also the logcat would show what happens when he clicks on the button. Finally, OP have you found the solution? If not please give us more details so we can help